# Ember - Get dynamic input value of element in component in test

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

So I have a simple component which looks like this:

```
<div class="my-div">{{ value }}</div>
{{input class="my-input" type="text" value=value}}
```

And I have two tests like this:

```
test('get text from div', function(assert) {

  this.set('value', 'my test value');
  this.render(hbs`{{input-test value=value}}`);

  assert.equal(this.$('.my-div').text(), 'my test value');

});

test('get value from input', function(assert) {

  this.set('value', 'my test value');
  this.render(hbs`{{input-test value=value}}`);

  assert.equal(this.$('.my-input').attr('value'), 'my test value');

});
```

The first test passes, but the second one fails. `this.$('.my-input').attr('value')` appears to be `undefined`. Why? How can I make this test pass?

Comment: `this.$('.my-input')` - this will return array of results, thats the reson for `undefined`.  `this.$('.my-input')[0].attr('value')` this will work.  As mentioned in answer `val()` will return the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `val()`:

```
assert.equal(this.$('.my-input').val(), 'my test value');
```

API ref: [jquery val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)